# Make a file in s3 public using python and boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have thins link below, and when I try to acess it it appears an xml file saying "Acess denied".

And I need to go to aws managment console and make this `part-0000` file public so I can acess it.

Do you know how can I give permissions using boto with python so I can acess this link without needed to go to aws managmet console and make the file public?

```
downloadLink = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/myFolder/uploadedfiles/2015423/part-00000'
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should give you an idea:

```
import boto.s3
conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('us-east-1')  # or region of choice
bucket = conn.get_bucket('myFolder')
key = bucket.lookup('uploadedfiles/2015423/part-00000')
key.set_acl('public-read')
```

In this case, `public-read` is one of the canned ACL policies supported by S3 and would allow anyone to read the file.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Says "no function named lookup". Using boto3

Comment: How to revoke the acl permission?

Answer (score 15):

```
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
import boto3

# ...
# have all the variables populated which are required below

client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                      aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
transfer = S3Transfer(client)
transfer.upload_file(filepath, bucket_name, folder_name+"/"+filename)
response = client.put_object_acl(ACL='public-read', Bucket=bucket_name, Key="%s/%s" % (folder_name, filename))
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work with boto 2.42.0 and Python 3

```
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
b = s3.get_bucket('brianray')
k = Key(b)
k.key = new_file_name
k.set_contents_from_filename(new_file_name)
k.set_acl('public-read')
k.generate_url(expires_in=0, query_auth=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Boto3 setting ACL. Good question/answers here.

```
bucket.Acl().put(ACL='public-read')
obj.Acl().put(ACL='public-read')
```

Use of `obj.Acl().put...` is very helpful when moving or manipulating items. Especially helpful if scripting/procedural.

via https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migrations3.html#access-controls.