# Make a file in s3 public using python and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I need an update for boto3 to this question
[Make a file in s3 public using python and boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422549/make-a-file-in-s3-public-using-python-and-boto)

```
s3.Bucket('gentle-persuader-emoji').put_object(Key=emoji_png_file, Body=image)
response = s3.object(emoji_png_file).put_object_acl('ACL=public-read')
```

gives error

```
AttributeError: 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Comment: Your error is due to the fact that `s3.object(emoji_png_file)` doesn't exist -- an object only exists in a bucket, not on its own.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are upload the object, the easiest method is to specify the Access Control List (ACL) as part of the upload:

```
s3.Bucket('gentle-persuader-emoji').put_object(Key=emoji_png_file, Body=image, ACL='public-read')
```

Alternatively, you may wish to add a [Bucket Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2) that applies to the whole bucket (or a specific path within the bucket), rather than applying the policy on each individual object.